# Restore SQL Server deleted files (.mdf, .ldf) (no backup)

Tags: sql-server, recovery

In SQL Server Management Studio, I made database file attached with files (.mdf, .ldf).

I mistakenly deleted the database file and then mdf & ldf files also were deleted.

Unfortunately, I did not backup any data and can't install any repair program. Could I restore the files? Is the program really needed?

Comment: Was that that database located in a virtual machine that happened to have an old snapshot?

Answer (score 2):

> I mistakenly deleted the database file and then mdf & ldf files also were deleted. Unfortunately, I did not backup any data and can't install any repair program. Could I restore the mdf, ldf files??

Short of using a disk data recovery tool to restore the `.mdf` and `.ldf` files, you're pretty much out of luck.